# AngularFireDatabase's method list not returning data from firebase in Angular

Tags: observable, angular6

I am trying to retrieve the data from firebase db to angular application.
How to retrieve the 'course' data from firebase?

[image]

My app.component.ts is as below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {
title = 'firebase-demo';
courseList:AngularFireList<[]>;
courses$;
course$;
constructor(db:AngularFireDatabase){
   this.courseList=db.list('/courses');
   this.course$=this.courseList.valueChanges()
     .subscribe(cousres=>{
      console.log(this.course$);
    })

  }
}
```

Firebase Db structure.
courses
C-01: 
"01"
C-02: 
"02"
C-03: 
"03"

Comment: the console.log is giving following output  =>  Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}

Comment: There is a typo in your sourcecode in your subscribe call. And there is a lot of info we are missing. Do you have a valid connection to the database, do you receive errors on your console? Edit your question, to make and keep it valuable for others.

Comment: Hi Bert, I have valid connection to db and find the way to display the content of db in list. will share the updated code. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have done changes into the code and and came up with following approach.
here courses1$ has snapshotChanges & courses2$ has valueChanges.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent {
 title = 'firebase-demo';
 courseList:AngularFireList<any[]>;
 courses1$;
 courses2$;
 course$;
 constructor(db:AngularFireDatabase){
 this.courseList=db.list('/courses');

 const itemsRef: AngularFireList<any[]>=db.list('/courses');
 this.courses1$ = itemsRef.snapshotChanges();
 this.courses2$ = itemsRef.valueChanges();
 console.log(this.courses1$); 
 }
```

}

To access and display the course elements i have used *ngFor with Async pipe

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor=" let course1 of courses1$ | async">{{course1.key}}</li>
  <!-- <li *ngFor=" let course2 of courses2$ | async">{{course2}}</li> -->

</ul>
```